# If for two suitable matrices $B$ and $C$, $AA^TB=AA^TC$ can we conclude that $A^TB=A^TC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ real matrix. If for two suitable matrices $B$ and $C$,
> $$AA^TB=AA^TC$$
> can we conclude that $A^TB=A^TC$?

I know $AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix. Every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. But I am not sure how to use this information.

Thanks for reading and helping me out with hints.

Answer (score 9):

$AA^TD=0\Rightarrow (A^TD)^T(A^TD)=D^TAA^TD=0\Rightarrow A^TD=0$. Now put $D=B-C$.

Comment: can you please explain how did you deduced that$ D^{T}A A^{T}D=0 => A^{T} D =0 $ ?  Can you please explain the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Ben $M^\ast M=0\Rightarrow\langle x,M^\ast Mx\rangle=0\,\forall x\Rightarrow\langle Mx,Mx\rangle=0\,\forall x\Rightarrow Mx=0\,\forall x\Rightarrow M=0$. This works on any real or complex inner product space of finite or infinite dimension.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually true. Multiply to both sides the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^+$ of $A$, giving us
$$A^+ A A^\top B = A^+ A A^\top C$$
According to the 6th [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Identities), we have $A^+ A A^\top = A^\top$, hence
$$A^\top B = A^\top C.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A = U S V^T$ be singular value decomposition of $A$ ($U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, $S$ is diagonal), so $A^T = V S U^T$. Let $X$ be such that $XSS^T = S$.

Then we have
$$AA^T B = AA^T C$$
$$USS^TU^T B = USS^TU^TC$$
$$SS^TU^TB = SS^TU^TC$$
$$XSS^TU^TB = XSS^TU^TC$$
$$SU^TB = SU^TC$$
$$VSU^TB = VSU^TC$$
$$A^T B = A^TC$$

Answer (score 2):

Should $AA^t$ have no zeroes on its diagonal it will be invertible and thus we can conclude $B=C$ and so $A^tB=A^tC$.